# Renaming images using Python3

Tags: python, image

I've been trying to rename over 1000 generated images in a folder. I am naming them by the folder name, batch, date plus an incrementing counter.

```
import os

def rename_files(directory, newname):
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    counter = 0
    for file in files:
        filetype = file.split(".")[-1]
        #
        os.rename(directory + '/' + file, directory + '/' + newname + str(counter) + '.' + filetype )
        print("Renaming file " + file + " to " + newname + str(counter) + '.' + filetype)
        counter += 1

rename( * "C:\Users\currrentUser\Pictures\unprocessed art\9-24-22-batch\AI_PICS_Realistic", "Batch_9_24_22")
```

The error I get back:

````
PS C:\Users\Popin>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Popin'; & 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Popin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '52801' '--' 'c:\Users\Popin\Rename_files_tool_project_youtube_example.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Popin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Popin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Popin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\Popin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 320, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "c:\Users\Popin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 294, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "c:\Users\Popin\Rename_files_tool_project_youtube_example.py", line 13
    rename( * "C:\Users\Popin\Pictures\unprocessed art\9-24-22-batch\AI_PICS_Realistic", "Batch_9_24_22")
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape```
````

Comment: Add a backslash before all backslashs or prefix you sting with `r`. Is it ok now ?

Comment: I recommend using `os.path.join()` instead of `+` to combine strings together for a file path.

Comment: p.s. If you google the error message, you will often find a solution much more quickly than posting here.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: Adding r corrected the error but the output I am seeking is still not happening.

Comment: @Jeremy That sounds like a new question. Feel free to post again with the current version of your code.